# nginx site shows blank page. No errors

Tags: linux, nginx, php, web-server, cgi

**Background**

I'm trying to get an nginx /php-fpm7 site up and running on an alpine linux server.

**Problem**

No errors appear when i navigate to it.  Cert is good.  And the in the /var/log/access.log file I see a GET request hitting the site. 
But ... the website/app that i've defined in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is NOT being loaded / triggered.  I should be prompted with a login page. 
Here are the various artifacts:

**What I've checked**

nginx is running and listening.  php-fpm is also running and listening

```
mywww:/etc/nginx/conf.d# netstat -lnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3979/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4480/nginx.conf
```

nginx.conf loads all confs in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
 mywww:/etc/nginx# cat nginx.conf | grep conf.d
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

default.conf looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        root /var/www/mywebapplication.com/public;
        server_name mywebbapplication.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/a/bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/a/thekey.key;
        ssl_protocols   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebapplication.log notice;
        index login.php;
        allow all;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /=404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index login.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

The login page exists:

```
  mywww:/etc/nginx# ls -lah /var/www/mywebapplication.com/public/login.php
 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          66 Apr 25  2019 /var/www/mywebapplication.com/public/login.php
```

Nginx Access Log files:

```
198.1.2.1 - - [24/Mar/2020:15:06:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebK│it/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"                                                                 │
198.1.2.1 - - [24/Mar/2020:15:06:29 +0000] "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Mobile Safari/537.36" "-"                                                        │
```

User / Group under which process is running:

```
mywww:/var/www/mywebapplication.com/public# ps aux | grep php
 3979 root      0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: master process (/etc/php7/php-fpm.conf)
 3986 nginx     0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: pool www
 3987 nginx     0:00 {php-fpm7} php-fpm: pool www
 4716 root      0:00 vim /etc/init.d/php-fpm7
 4719 root      0:00 grep php
```

The user for nginx is "nginx":

```
mywww:/etc/nginx# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep user   
user nginx nginx;
```

is it ok that the nginx master process is running as root?

Not sure what else I should check for.